# Github connector Google Data Studio throwing error when trying to load repo info

Tags: looker-studio

Error ID: 6b189640

getting this error ID when I am trying to load information into my report on Google Data Studio. Anyone run into this before? When I check the developer logs it just says failed at getData() and nothing else.

[image]

Comment: Did you deploy your own version of the connector or using an existing deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup the oAuth app on the organization instead of creating the oAuth app on the account of an admin for the organization that I needed access to its repos.